# SQL Express - Could I partition an exisiting table to solve 10GB file size limitation?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, sql-server-express

One of our custom reached the 10GB size limitation of SQL-Express edition. There are 2 tables contains too many training data. Could we partition tables on sql express edition? Is there any help link for this issue?

We had design a solution to refactor the tables and codes. But Partition tables sound like much easier.

Comment: The maximum database size is 10GB, not object size. Partitioning the table will not reduce the size of the database.

Comment: Thank you. We will try to spilt it to several mdf files.

Answer (score 1):

No, man - unfortunately you can do nothing.

```
SQL Express 2005 & 2008 R1  4 Gb database size limit
SQL Express 2008 R2         10 Gb database size limit
SQL Express 2012            10 Gb database size limit
SQL Express 2014            10 Gb database size limit
SQL Express 2016            10 Gb database size limit
```

I have try before to find a work around because I wanted to use T-SQL syntax to manipulate some data and did not succeed.

Also, even if you find a way there is always possibility to violate the SQL Server license.

Use another database (there are open source solutions) or upgrade to standard edition.

Comment: To give my two cents: When your customer reaches a file size of 10 GB and shrinking the files after deleting data that are not needed anymore does not help - it would be time to upgrade the server edition.

Comment: Thanks to M$. We will try to spilt it to several mdf files.

Answer (score 1):

Just create another database and move your table to the newly created database and do a cross database query.

You can even create a synonym to it so everything will be transparent to your front-end code.